# SVG нарисовать линию соединения между двумя прямоугольниками

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, svg

В настоящее время я программирую редактор диаграмм на javascript с помощью SVG.

У меня возникла проблема, связанная с соединением прямоугольников. Я нашел много ресурсов, чтобы нарисовать связь между кругами, но ничего о прямоугольниках.

Итак, теперь я знаю, как я могу нарисовать линию соединения между двумя прямоугольниками, перетащив линию с помощью мыши, но соединение отображается внутри прямоугольников, потому что я вычисляю соединение из средней точки прямоугольников.

Как вы можете видеть на картинке ниже, я подумал, но не дошел до последнего шага.

Я просто хочу нарисовать линию, отмеченную красным.

Позже я хочу перетащить прямоугольники, и линия должна быть обновлена, но сейчас мне просто нужно вычислить эту линию.

У кого-нибудь есть хорошее предложение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Svg draw connection line between two rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50252070/7394871) от участника  [@Korbson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9757272/korbson).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50252070/7394871

Comment: кстати для этих целей есть универсальное средство: https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо. Отличная вещь однако

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, у вас есть два прямоугольника, и вы знаете их центр (`cx1, cy1`) и (`cx2, cy2`). У вас также есть ширина и высота, разделенные на 2 (то есть расстояние от центра до сторон): (`w1, h1`) и (`w2, h2`).

The distance between them is:

Расстояние между ними составляет:

```
var dx = cx2 - cx1;
var dy = cy2 - cy1;
```

Затем вы можете рассчитать точку пересечения двух прямоугольников с помощью:

```
var p1 = getIntersection(dx, dy, cx1, cy1, w1, h1);
var p2 = getIntersection(-dx, -dy, cx2, cy2, w2, h2);
```

Где, [getIntersection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

```
function getIntersection(dx, dy, cx, cy, w, h) {
  if (Math.abs(dy / dx) < h / w) {
    // Попадание в вертикальный край box1
    return [cx + (dx > 0 ? w : -w), cy + dy * w / Math.abs(dx)];
   } else {
    // Попадание в горизонтальный край box1 box1
    return [cx + dx * h / Math.abs(dy), cy + (dy > 0 ? h : -h)];
    }
};
```

Ниже пример:

```js
var rect1 = document.getElementById('rect1');
var rect2 = document.getElementById('rect2');
var cxn = document.getElementById('connection');

updateConnection();

function updateConnection() {
  // Top left coordinates
  var x1 = parseFloat(rect1.getAttributeNS(null, 'x'));
  var y1 = parseFloat(rect1.getAttributeNS(null, 'y'));
  var x2 = parseFloat(rect2.getAttributeNS(null, 'x'));
  var y2 = parseFloat(rect2.getAttributeNS(null, 'y'));

  // Half widths and half heights
  var w1 = parseFloat(rect1.getAttributeNS(null, 'width')) / 2;
  var h1 = parseFloat(rect1.getAttributeNS(null, 'height')) / 2;
  var w2 = parseFloat(rect2.getAttributeNS(null, 'width')) / 2;
  var h2 = parseFloat(rect2.getAttributeNS(null, 'height')) / 2;

  // Center coordinates
  var cx1 = x1 + w1;
  var cy1 = y1 + h1;
  var cx2 = x2 + w2;
  var cy2 = y2 + h2;

  // Distance between centers
  var dx = cx2 - cx1;
  var dy = cy2 - cy1;

  var p1 = getIntersection(dx, dy, cx1, cy1, w1, h1);
  var p2 = getIntersection(-dx, -dy, cx2, cy2, w2, h2);

  cxn.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', p1[0]);
  cxn.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', p1[1]);
  cxn.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', p2[0]);
  cxn.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', p2[1]);
}

function getIntersection(dx, dy, cx, cy, w, h) {
if (Math.abs(dy / dx) < h / w) {
  // Hit vertical edge of box1
  return [cx + (dx > 0 ? w : -w), cy + dy * w / Math.abs(dx)];
 } else {
  // Hit horizontal edge of box1
  return [cx + dx * h / Math.abs(dy), cy + (dy > 0 ? h : -h)];
  }
};

function makeDraggable(evt) {
  var svg = evt.target;
  svg.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
  svg.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
  svg.addEventListener('mouseup', endDrag);

  function getMousePosition(evt) {
    var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
    return {
      x: (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
      y: (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
    };
  }

  var selectedElement, offset;

  function startDrag(evt) {
    if (evt.target.classList.contains('draggable')) {
      selectedElement = evt.target;
      offset = getMousePosition(evt);
      offset.x -= parseFloat(selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "x"));
      offset.y -= parseFloat(selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "y"));
    }
  }

  function drag(evt) {
    if (selectedElement) {
      var coord = getMousePosition(evt);
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "x", coord.x - offset.x);
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "y", coord.y - offset.y);
      updateConnection();
    }
  }

  function endDrag(evt) {
    selectedElement = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.static {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.draggable {
  cursor: move;
  fill: #007bff;
  fill-opacity: 0.1;
  stroke: #007bff;
  stroke-width: 0.2;
}

#connection {
  stroke-width: 0.1;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 20" onload="makeDraggable(evt)" width="400" height="200">
    
  <rect id="rect1" class="draggable" x="4" y="5" width="4" height="3"/>
  <rect id="rect2" class="draggable" x="18" y="5" width="3" height="5"/>
  <line id="connection" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50261758/7394871) от участника  [@Peter Collingridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/566920/peter-collingridge).</sub>